# Compiling a different file in TeXShop

Tags: compiling, texshop

In TeXShop, is it possible to use the ctrl/cmd+T hotkey to compile a different file than the one that's open?

When distributing the project into multiple files, it would be nice to have a hotkey which always compiles the associated main.tex file. Normally, I have main.tex open in the first tab of the window, and a hotkey for compiling the first tab would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made two files

### File `estenmain.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\input{estensecondary}

\end{document}
```

### File `estensecondary.tex`

```latex
% !TEX root = estenmain.tex

Hello world.
```

Then clicking “Typeset” in the window of the second file, the root file is compiled.

The “magic line” can be added with a choice from the menu “Macros > Root”. A box for choosing a file will appear and you'll be given the choice between a relative path or an absolute path. The former is best.

Comment: Please also read `Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!